# How to recieve a message from a MQ queue and publish the same message to a topic using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am developing a spring boot application which should recieve message from  IBM MQ and publish the same message onto a topic in SpringBoot JMS. I am able to recieve the Message in the `onMessage()` of `MessageListener` but not able to publish the same message onto a topic. Need help regarding this.

This is the MessageListener Class implementation

```
@Component
public class QueueListener implements MessageListener{

    @Autowired
    private TopicMessageCreator topicCreator;


    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                String json = ((TextMessage) message).getText();


                topicCreator.pushMessageToTopic(json);
/*************************************************************/
```

I have tried calling a service from `onMessage()` method of the `MessageListener`. In the service I am doing `jmsTemplate.send` but I get Error message which says "Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set"
This is the Class which publishes the message to topic

```
@Service
public class TopicMessageCreator {

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("jmsTopicTemplate")
     private JmsTemplate jmsTopicTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Servers server;


    public void pushMessageToTopic(String jsonString) {

            jmsTopicTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {

                    @Override
                    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                        TextMessage text = session.createTextMessage(jsonString);
                        session.createTopic(server.getTopic());
                        return text;
                    }
                });


    }
```

Comment: There appears to be a mismatch in that you are passing a `String` into the method `topicCreator.pushMessageToTopic`, but it is expecting a `List<String>`

Comment: My bad. I have modified